# Show Login name on welcome form

Tags: vba, ms-access, authentication

I have made a database in VBA access. I want to display login name on welcome form. Please guide me in this regard. I m trying to pass username from login form to welcome form through public variable but not working. My code is as under:-
**Login Form Code**

```
enter code here
Public strUserID As String
Private Sub cmdLogin_Click()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
 Dim strSQL As String

If IsNull(Me.txtLoginID) Or Me.txtLoginID = "" Then
MsgBox "Enter user Name.....", vbInformation, "Whiz Alert!"
Me.txtLoginID.SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If
If IsNull(Me.txtPassword) Or Me.txtPassword = "" Then
MsgBox "Enter Password.....", vbInformation, "Whiz Alert!"
 Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If
strSQL = "SELECT UserID FROM User WHERE LoginID = """ & Me.txtLoginID.Value & """ AND Password = """ & Me.txtPassword.Value & """"
 Set db = CurrentDb
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
 If rst.EOF Then
MsgBox "Incorrect Username/Password.", vbCritical, "Login Error"
Me.txtLoginID.SetFocus
Else
DoCmd.Close acForm, "Index", acSaveYes
DoCmd.OpenForm "HomePage", acNormal, , , , acWindowNormal
DoCmd.Close acForm, "UserLoginForm", acSaveYes
 End If
Set db = Nothing
Set rst = Nothing
End Sub
Private Sub txtLoginID_AfterUpdate()
strUserID = Me.txtLoginID
End Sub
```

**Welcome form Code**

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
Me.txtUser = UserLoginForm.strUserID
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to assign public variables in a module if you want to be able to use them across access objects. It is currently only in scope for the Login Form. As an aside you should really space out your subs and use indentation.

Answer (score 0):

I would move the login operation to a separate function and act according to the return value.

A simple login method which returns `True` if login was successful, or `False` if it wasn't. No need to open a recordset here, a simple `DCount()` will do.

```
Public Function TryToLogin(ByVal Username As Variant, ByVal Password As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo Trap

    'validation
    Select Case True
        Case IsNull(Username):
            MsgBox "Enter user Name.....", vbInformation, "Whiz Alert!"
            GoTo Leave
        Case IsNull(Password):
            MsgBox "Enter Password.....", vbInformation, "Whiz Alert!"
            GoTo Leave
    End Select

    'credentials correct?
    If DCount("UserID", "User", "LoginID='" & Username & "' AND Password='" & Password & "'") = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Incorrect Username/Password.", vbExclamation, "Login Error"
        GoTo Leave
    End If

    'login successful
    TryToLogin = True

Leave:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

Trap:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Leave
End Function
```

---

The method (I assume a button click event) to call the login function. Check the return value and act based on it. If successful, you can pass the Username using the form's `OpenArgs` parameter. I presume the welcome form is the homepage?

```
Private Sub Button_Click()

    If Not TryToLogin(txtLoginID.Value, txtPassword.Value) Then Exit Sub

    With DoCmd
        .Close acForm, "Index", acSaveYes
        .OpenForm "HomePage", acNormal, , , , acWindowNormal, txtLoginID.Value
        .Close acForm, "UserLoginForm", acSaveYes
    End With

End Sub
```

---

Lastly, handle the `OpenArgs` in the welcome form's `Load()` event.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    If Not IsNull(OpenArgs) Then
        'the OpenArgs now holds the username.
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Dear Boss, I m very grateful to you. certainly your method is easy to understand. Only one confusion is still here i,e where on the HomePage it will appear. I mean text box is required to display the username or not.

Comment: Certainly not a boss. :) The `OpenArgs` is simply a way to pass data to the opening form. From there you can populate a textbox if you want, it's up to you. In other words you use the OpenArgs to pass the username from the login from to the homepage form.